# VectorBT backtesting python intraday problem

Tags: python, back-testing

I'm using VectorBT in python to backtest a strategy, however as soon as I get any intraday data with gaps, this is what happens:
[image]

Obviously, the gaps are nights/holidays etc, and because of that the indicators are calculated incorrectly - **this is not just a plotting issue**. What can I do to fix it? I haven't found anything in the documentation

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: @A7DC actually yes, even though it seemed to have been a problem with VBT, it was actually incomplete data + plotting issues. VBT is fine after all :D